# Insert html video player in As2 page

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, video, embed

I have a online courses with a lot of videos. These videos are in Vimeo for the app of this courses but I use flv loaded to the server in my flash version and the administrator wants to get off these flv.

**Cause I don't know a bit of AS3, i can't use the vimeo api**. So:

How can I display a webpage (where an html player will be running the video) in my swf? Like some kind of web object. The result, must be the video page inserted in the swf area

Please, be specific in your answer, my knowledge of coding is poor.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You need to show some research efforts. SO is for specific questions. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, I know... but i have nothing... just a as2 line and a simple html that wont load... i'll try to post it in a comprehensive way

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this would be to setup an `ExternalInterface` in the Flash course that will communicate with the page. From there, Flash can call a method that is responsible for rendering an `iframe` embed of the Vimeo player. You'll probably have to pass both the `video_id` and the location where the video should be displayed (`x/y` in the event that it changes).

Once you have the javascript setup to render the `iframe` embed where you need it, you can interact with the player via the Javascript API (https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api). The player would essentially be rendered above the Flash (kind of like a lightbox), but will allow the control that you need.

You can also setup whatever playback controls that you need to pass from Flash to Javascript, and eventually to the `iframe` via the API.

Please let me know if you need any more clarification on how this can be setup.